# express-validation password validation (equal passwords)

Tags: node.js, validation, express

Trying to validate some form inputs with express-validation.
Everything works fine but cant figure out how I can check for equal password.

```
// form validation
req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email not valid').isEmail();
req.checkBody('username', 'username is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'password is required').notEmpty();
//req.checkbody('password2', 'Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);

// check for errors
var errors = req.validationErrors();
if(errors) {
  res.render('register', {
    errors: errors,
    name: name,
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    password2: password2
});
```

Here I get this:
[image]

As you can see, this works just fine.
but after using:

```
  req.checkbody('password2', 'Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);
```

[image]

It wont work and as I google around this has to work tho!
Someone familiar with this issue?
Btw, just started to learn node.js, and sorry for by mad englisch.
If someone needs some more information I am happy to provide.
Thanks

ps.
Already tried:

```
req.assent('password2', 'Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);
```

Comment: `checkbody` is missing a capital B...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seem everything ok may be you forget a check:

```
req.checkBody('password', 'password is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2', 'password2 is required').notEmpty();
req.checkbody('password2', 'Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);
```

Comment: no he forget the second check , No check password2 empty

Comment: Ow jeez, this is a bit embarrassing. It was the capital B :|. What is wrong with me? ;p

Comment: oh, sometime I have prolems with case-sensitive